# How to create five different figures with the same format in one script from a single DataFrame based on a single Excel file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am still very new to Python so this is likely an easy question but I have yet to locate a satisfactory answer.  I have data from five different sources which I am trying to plot in one script after loading the data from a Excel file to a single DataFrame.  As it is now, I only know how to graph one source at a time or all 5 in a single figure (or somwhere between 1 and 5).  Here is my code, the entire script.  It may not all be necessary but I have included it all just in case.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import datetime as datetime
from datetime import *

#Import data from Excel File
data2007 = pd.ExcelFile('f:\Python\Learning 19-4-2013\Data 2007.xls')
table2007 = data2007.parse('Sheet1', skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5], index=None)

#Plot data for first meter
ax = plot.figure(figsize=(7,4), dpi=100).add_subplot(111)
FirstMeter = table2007_3.columns[0]
Meter1 = table2007_3[FirstMeter]
Meter1.plot(ax=ax, style='-v')

#Plot data for second meter
SecondMeter = table2007_3.columns[1]
Meter2 = table2007_3[SecondMeter]
Meter2.plot(ax=ax, style='-v')

#Plot data for third meter
ThirdMeter = table2007_3.columns[2]
Meter3 = table2007_3[ThirdMeter]
Meter3.plot(ax=ax, style='v-')

#Plot data for fourth meter
FourthMeter = table2007_3.columns[3]
Meter4 = table2007_3[FourthMeter]
Meter4.plot(ax=ax, style='v-')

#Plot data for fifth meter
FifthMeter = table2007_3.columns[4]
Meter5 = table2007_3[FifthMeter]
Meter5.plot(ax=ax, style='v-')

#Command to show plots
plot.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are making a new Series (e.g., `Meter1`) out of each column of your DataFrame and then plotting them individually on the same axes. Instead, you can plot the DataFrame itself. Pandas assumes you want to plot each column as a separate line on the same plot, which is exactly what you seem to be doing here.

```
table_2007.plot(style='v-')
```

or perhaps `table_2007[0:4].plot(style='v-')` if there are other columns which you need to leave out.

By default, it also generates a legend, which you can suppress with  the keyword argument `legend=False`.

If you want separate figures, as the title of your question suggests the `subplots=True` argument might get the job done.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out you can plot directly from the DataFrame.   That will be useful on another project. However, it seems in this case the first option still puts the entire DataFrame in one Figure.  Also, the second option only prints the first 4 rows of data for all of the columns.  Unfortunately, neither of these do what I need.  Also, having the graphs as subplots is not very helpful because I need four separate figures, not just four separate graphs.  Any other advice?  Thank you!

Comment: Making them individually isn't so bad (``table_2007[0].plot(...)``, etc.). But I suppose you could loop through the columns, calling ``figure()`` each time to make a separate figure.